# Assigning values to read-only attributes when de-serializing sklearn model objects using json

Tags: python, scikit-learn, metaclass

I am trying to create my own method of saving and loading sklearn DecisionTreeRegressor models to and from JSON. Pickling the models is no longer a good option since I ran into compatibility issues with the pickle files. My work is based on the tutorial by Sebastian Raschka: http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/rasbt/python-machine-learning-book/blob/master/code/bonus/scikit-model-to-json.ipynb
I encountered a problem with some model attributes being read-only when trying to assign values to them. Looks like they were set up that way in the parent class.

```
class DecisionTreeRegressor_json(DecisionTreeRegressor):
    def save_json(self):
        # create main parameter dictionary
        list_main_exclude = ['_get_param_names', '_validate_X_predict', 'apply', 'fit',
                             'fit_transform', 'get_params', 'predict', 'presort', 'splitter',
                             'tree_', 'decision_path', 'score', 'set_params', 'transform', '_save_json_w_ndarray',
                             'save_json', 'load_json', '_set_params']
        list_main = [i for i in dir(self) if not i.endswith('__') and
                     not i.startswith('_abc') and not i in list_main_exclude]
        attrs_main = {i: getattr(self, i) for i in list_main}
        # create tree parameter dictionary
        list_tree_exclude = ['apply', 'compute_feature_importances', 'decision_path', 'predict']
        list_tree = [i for i in dir(self.tree_) if not i.endswith('__') and not i in list_tree_exclude]
        attrs_tree = {i: getattr(self.tree_, i) for i in list_tree}
        # dump dictionaries to json
        with codecs.open(medir + '/params.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as outfile:
            self._save_json_w_ndarray(attrs_main, outfile)
        with codecs.open(medir + '/tree.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as outfile:
            self._save_json_w_ndarray(attrs_tree, outfile)

    def _save_json_w_ndarray(self, dict, outfile):
        for k in dict:
            if isinstance(dict[k], np.ndarray):
                dict[k] = dict[k].tolist()
        json.dump(dict,
                     outfile,
                     separators=(',', ':'),
                     sort_keys=True,
                     indent=4)

    def load_json(self):
        dtr = DecisionTreeRegressor()
        main_text = codecs.open(medir + '/params.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8').read()
        tree_text = codecs.open(medir + '/tree.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8').read()
        main_params = json.loads(main_text)
        tree_params = json.loads(tree_text)
        self._set_params(self, **main_params)
        self.tree_ = Tree(tree_params['n_features'], np.array(tree_params['n_classes']), tree_params['n_outputs'])
        self._set_params(self.tree_, **tree_params)

    def _set_params(self, obj, **param_dict):
        for k in param_dict:
            print k
            print param_dict[k]
            if isinstance(param_dict[k], list):
                setattr(obj, k, np.array(param_dict[k]))
            else:
                setattr(obj, k, param_dict[k])
```

One of the attributes I cannot modify is 'feature_importances_' which is of the ndarray type. If I load a pickle, the attribute gets the expected numpy array. How does pickle do it? How can I do it for JSON?
This is what the fitted model object looks like that I'm trying to recreate from JSON:

[dir(object)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GlJGf.png)

The error trying to set "feature_importances_":

setattr(obj, k, np.array(param_dict[k]))
AttributeError: can't set attribute

Comment: Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/a24c8b46/sklearn/tree/tree.py#L495), `feature_importances_` is a method which uses `tree.compute_feature_importances()` method. So if your `tree` has been propertly initialized, then just calling the `feature_importances_` should give you the same result, which you are trying to set.]

Comment: This is indeed the case with feature_importances_. The problem is that the Tree object itself has a few read-only properties that are populated when the model is trained. I haven't figured out yet how to establish the Tree object persistence without using pickle or joblib. Populating the non read-only attributes and then calling the getters produced incorrect values.